# How do you use mysql to only return a record if no conflicts exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to have a SELECT statement only return a result if there exist no records in the database that conflict with the conditions?

For example, people can reserve a table for two-hour blocks. A new reservation should only be allowed if there are no reservations that overlap with the new request.

Something like the following doesn't work because as long as there is one reservation that doesn't match it, then the statement will find that record and return it:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE (startTime NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (endTime NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

Comment: Why wont that query work?

Comment: What would that result be? Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to return a result for your SELECT statement when no records conflicts with the conditions you should use EXISTS operator. It is a boolean operator.

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE (startTime NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (endTime NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?))
```

Alternatively, perhaps more logical in the context

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE (startTime BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (endTime BETWEEN ? AND ?))
```

Edit: one query, not returning all rows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN false ELSE true END as free FROM reservations WHERE (startTime BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (endTime BETWEEN ? AND ?))
```

Comment: @Michael . . . I'm a little baffled on why you accepted an answer that could -- conceivably -- return all the rows in `reservations`.  That does not seem to be what you are asking for.

Comment: I was a bit confused by the question, but it states "a result if there exist no records". The wanted result itself was not defined clearly, so it is "a" result. ;p

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was already taking care of that case on my side, but I should have clarified it in the question as you say.

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN` is not the correct comparison for two time frames.  Instead, two timeframes have overlap when both are true:

- One starts before the second ends
- One ends after the other starts.

You can get the overlaps using:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reservations r
WHERE startTime < :endtime and endTime > :starttime;
```

It is easy enough to convert this to logical value using a subquery:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM reservations r
               WHERE r.startTime < :endtime and r.endTime > :starttime
              ) as has_overlap
```

Or use `NOT EXISTS` for the negative logic (`has_no_overlap`).